# Nginx load balancer returns bad gateway error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing

I have three servers; two web servers running nginx and a load balancer also running nginx. I can ping/telnet/curl between the load balancer and web servers but when I try to go to the load balancer IP in my browser I get a 502 error.

Here is my web server nginx config file:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /home/user/website.com/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    server_name 1.1.1.1;
    access_log /home/user/website.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/user/website.com/logs/error.log;
    root /home/user/website.com/public/;
    index index.php;

    set $skip_cache 0; # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP if ($request_method = POST) { set $skip_cache 1$

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
            fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
            expires 30d;
    }

}
```

Here is my load balancer nginx config file:

```
upstream backend {
server 1.1.1.1:9000;
server 1.1.1.2:9000;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

server_name 1.1.1.3;

 location ~* \.php$/ {
        gzip on;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass backend;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I am not getting anything out of the ordinary in my access/error log files on my web servers but I am getting this error on my load balancer nginx error log:

```
2015/08/06 03:47:59 [error] 3650#0: *17 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 104.183.250.151, server: 1.1.1.3, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://1.1.1.2:80/", host: "1.1.1.3"
```

As a side note, I am not actually 1.1.1.1 IPs. I have replaced my actual IPs for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the upstream (that is, the web server you're proxying to) is closing the connection before any response headers were sent.  Examine the logs for the backend web server to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't see anything in the logs on the web servers but I did realize it's probably a php-fpm issue. I adjusted my load balancer config. I'm no longer getting a 502 error, but I am only seeing the load balancer server contents when I browse to the load balancer ip, not the web server contents.

Answer (score 0):

In the upstream section of the balancer, you tell the LoadBalancer to connect over port 9000 but the virtualhost is listening om port 80, and not 9000. Thats why the bad gateway